# How to add the Google Adsense mobile ads on Blogger blog?

Tags: adsense

Over 30% of the traffic to my blog comes from Java mobile users who can't able to see the Web Adsense ads and now I want to add the mobile Adsense ads on my site Techdracula.com which is hosted on the blogger but the problem is that the mobile Ad code just displayed on my blog instead of showing the Ad (so I removed the ad code now). I want to know which type of Ad code I want to choose for mobile ads and will the Adsense mobile ads work on the Blogger blog?

Please refer -> ***i.stack.imgur.com/VhLge.gif*** for seeing the options given for me in ma Adsense dashboard for creating a mobile ad.

I want to switch the google adsense ad (mobile vs regular) based on user agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can review 4 Easy Steps

1. Blogger Dashbord > Layout.
2. Click Edit on Blog Posts section.
3. Click on Show Ads between Posts.
4. Select your preferences and Save.

If you don’t see ads running, ensure that you have added at least one AdSense code directly to your template that works on normal web browsers.

Note: You won’t be able to perform step 3 of this tutorial unless you have enabled AdSense from your Blogger Dashboard.

This, you can do by clicking Earnings from the options available on the left side of your screen. If you already have an AdSense account, they are instructions on how you can link your blog to your existing account.

View demo : [eBooklyn.blogspot.com](http://ebooklyn.blogspot.com)